# How to get HTML content of webpage from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I would like to scrape some contents from a dynamic web page (seems it is developed in MVC).

Data scraping logics are done with HTML agility, but now the issue is,
HTML returned while requesting for URL from browser and web response of the URL from ASP.NET web request is different.

Mainly browser response has dynamic data I need (renders based on the value passed in query string), but the `WebResponse` result is different.

Could you please help me to get the actual content of the dynamic web page view `WebRequest`.

Below is the code I used to read:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
request.Method = "Get";
//Get the response
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
//Read the stream from the response
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: In what way is the "WebResponse result" different?

Comment: The HTML content i get from View Source of web URL is different with HTML content for ASP.Net web response.

For Example:
If the URL is for restaurants in specific post code, browser requested HTML has list of restaurants in that area, but the Web Response HTML has no restaurants in that DIV.

<div><li>restaurant 1</li><li>Restaurant 2</li></div -- Browser Resposne.

<div><li></li><li></li></div> -- ASP.Net web response

Answer (score 19):

To get the content of any web page using `HttpWebRequest`...

```
// We will store the html response of the request here
string siteContent = string.Empty;

// The url you want to grab
string url = "http://google.com";

// Here we're creating our request, we haven't actually sent the request to the site yet...
// we're simply building our HTTP request to shoot off to google...
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

// Right now... this is what our HTTP Request has been built in to...
/*
    GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
    Host: google.com
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
    Connection: Keep-Alive
*/


// Wrap everything that can be disposed in using blocks... 
// They dispose of objects and prevent them from lying around in memory...
using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())  // Go query google
using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())               // Load the response stream
using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))       // Load the stream reader to read the response
{
    siteContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // Read the entire response and store it in the siteContent variable
}

// magic...
Console.WriteLine (siteContent);
```

Comment: If you're going to down vote it... write a comment at least explaining why so that I can improve it, and others don't get the impression that this solution doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for this, but all i need to know is why request for URL from  browser returns correct result (HTML), that ASP.Net web request can't.

Is this because of requested site was developed in ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: It will be able to... there may be other things going on, but no matter what it is... I can assure you that if you can visit it in a web browser... you can visit it using the HttpWebRequest class because they both use HTTP. The issue may be that there are redirects going on through JavaScript... or maybe AJAX requests firing off once the page you requested was loaded... Download Fiddler... and look at the HTTP requests that are happening once you visit the page in a browser

Comment: THIS WORKS PERFECTLY. It does this request via clientside. So no need to try this on client side with jquery etc.