# How to get Facebook video thumbnail image from facebook video url in asp.net using c#

Tags: facebook, video, c#-4.0, video-thumbnails

User uploaded videos thumbnail image not rendering with video_Id. e.x for below url I am not able to get a thumbnail image

https://graph.facebook.com/841765655909231/picture

https://www.facebook.com/AyuTheOnlyQueen/videos/%E6%B5%9C%E5%B4%8E%E3%81%82%E3%82%86%E3%81%BF-step-by-step-full-song/841765655909231/

Comment: There is no `picture` for videos. If you had bothered to check the documentation, you could have known that already - and also found out, that there is a `thumbnails` edge instead.

Comment: It's not obvious how your ASP.net code is trying to get the image, so no-one can advise you why it's not working.

Comment: @AvinashKumar any feedback? Did my answer solve your "find image" problem?

Answer (score 1):

> *"...For below url I am not able to get a thumbnail image"*
>
> https://www.facebook.com/AyuTheOnlyQueen/videos/%E6%B5%9C%E5%B4%8E%E3%81%82%E3%82%86%E3%81%BF-step-by-step-full-song/841765655909231/

You can try these steps:

1) Use `HttpWebRequest` to [load the page's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002854/2057709) (HTML) into some `String` variable.

2) Use String functions (like `indexOf`) to find the following within received HTML text...

- Find first occurrence of `<video` and note that start position. Example integer is `startPos`.
- From that new start position, now find the first occurrence of `<img class=`. Update the `startPos`.
- Now from start Pos of `<img class=`, find position of first occurence of `src="`. Update the `startPos`.
- Add `+5` to `startPos` to skip 5 letters of `src="`. Now grab everything up to next occurrence of `"`.
- That is the video's image URL.

URL from web page and resulting image below :

```
https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.5256-10/11114598_841767259242404_606288892_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQmoGDOf_G7khNZvfjXVDADkAqsBMJ6R89r4FgD_5i1xJvdFSsBQfc7M-mrW1bA_s-M&_nc_ht=scontent-lhr3-1.xx&oh=35d15b4527748ed7956c2276ab158eb4&oe=5DB1C235
```

[image]

Comment: To summarize: Facebook has made it so difficult to use their api that it's now considered easier to download the facebook video page and grope the code for the img tag to get a small thumbnail.  Ridiculous.