# ASP.NET MVC C# - How to add headers in http request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, postman

I need to extract data from an URL which returns HTML data. I can do it using Postman I just need the correct syntax to do it in ASP.NET MVC C#.

```
https://www.dsebd.org/ajax/load-news.php
```

**Headers**

```
accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
sec-fetch-dest:empty
sec-fetch-mode:cors
sec-fetch-site:same-origin
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

And the method is **Post**.

Can anyone please share me the syntax in ASP.NET MVC C#?

Comment: What's the data you are getting in postman?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The data returns an HTML table

Comment: Will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002778/how-to-get-html-content-of-webpage-from-asp-net

Comment: And This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-website-in-c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get HTML code from website in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642196/get-html-code-from-website-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Abdullah-Al-Nahian Glad to hear you have fixed the problem. According to your question title and the description "How to get data from this URL", it seems that you want to get the response headers from the response, instead of adding all the headers in the request. If you change the question to "how to add headers in http request", it might be easier for us to understand what you want.

Comment: Its not me who down voted it.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thank you so much. My title was misleading. I have changed it now according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Guys I wanted the correct format. I never asked for the rules of web scraping.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format(url));
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html, */*; q=0.01";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
```

This is all I asked. Thanks for your help though.